# use "key" as a column name in data.table constructor

Tags: r, data.table

Out of interest. Any alternatives and short to type way (other than a couple I think of) to construct a data.table with a column called `key` as there is a construction (function) argument called also key?

Example with outputs:

```
library(data.table)

# :(
data.table("key" = 1:3)[]
data.table(key = 1:3)[]
# Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)

# :|
setDT(data.frame(key = 1:3))[]
setnames(data.table(foo = 1:3), "foo", "key")[]
setDT(list(key = 1:3))[]
# return:
#    key
# 1:   1
# 2:   2
# 3:   3
```

Comment: those options seem ok, another alternative: `data.table(1:3)[, .(key=V1)]`

Comment: What do you expect the answer to your question would be? Looks like you have no problem that others can help you to solve.